# Explicitly clear localstorage on browser close for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, jwt, local-storage

I hve an app with React front and java back. I'm using JWT and keep the token in localstorage. How to clear localstorage when I close the whole browser? For react.
My menu component is here (the one I change based on the presence of the token. isUserLoggedIn checks if there is a token.

```
class MenuComponent extends Component {
  componentWillUnmount() {
    localStorage.clear();
  }
  render() {
    const isUserLoggedIn = AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn();
    return (
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand='lg' bg='dark' variant='dark'>
        <Navbar.Brand href=''>MAP-Runner</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav' />
        <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
          <Nav>
            {!isUserLoggedIn && (
              <li>
                <Link className='nav-link' to='/login'>
                  Вход
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
            {isUserLoggedIn && (
              <li>
                <Link className='nav-link' to='/calculations'>
                  Расчеты
                </Link>
                <Link
                  className='nav-link'
                  to={{ pathname: `/calculation-types` }}
                >
                  Типы расчетов
                </Link>
                <Link className='nav-link' to={{ pathname: `/group-settings` }}>
                  Настройки кластеров
                </Link>
                <Link className='nav-link' to={{ pathname: `/ost-docs` }}>
                  Док-ты остатков
                </Link>
                <Link className='nav-link' to={{ pathname: `/artlists` }}>
                  Списки артикулов
                </Link>
                <Link className='nav-link' to={{ pathname: `/color-schemas` }}>
                  Цветовые схемы
                </Link>
                <Link
                  className='nav-link'
                  to='/logout'
                  onClick={AuthenticationService.logout}
                >
                  Выход
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(MenuComponent);
```

Comment: Just try to delete it in componentWillUnmount lifecycle ?

Comment: in every component? Even if I don't log out and just close the whole browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you need to use Local Storage only, then you can run a code when the App Component is mounted for the first time that clears Local Storage:

> localStorage.clear()

Although, the better option would be, as Raymond Camden pointed out, to use Session Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage instead of localStorage.